# I cannot insert a word to mysql

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['zodis'])) { 
strpos($_POST['zodis'], ' ');
if($pos > 0) {
    print '<h2> Only 1 word. </h2>';
} else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `zodziai` (`id` ,`zodis` ,`date`)VALUES (NULL , '"$_POST['zodis']"',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    }
}
```

Where i made a mistake? Im new in PHP

it shows

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   `C:\wamp\www\php_mysql.php` on line 19

Comment: sorry, line 19 is $query = "INSERT INTO `zodziai` (`id` ,`zodis` ,`date`)VALUES (NULL , '"$_POST['zodis']"',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";

Comment: what kind of field type is your date column?

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO zodziai (id,zodis,date)VALUES (NULL, '".$_POST['zodis']."',".time().");";
```

your id field isn't autoincreament?
what kind of type field is your date field?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `.`.

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO `zodziai` (`id` ,`zodis` ,`date`)VALUES (NULL , '" . $_POST['zodis'] . "',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
```

Comment: Also, don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They are in the process of becoming deprecated. If you are learning PHP, do yourself a favour and use the `mysqli_*` functions or PDO objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you mix strings and variables, you should use "." to concatenate them:

...VALUES (NULL , '".$_POST['zodis']."',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)...

(Note the point (.) before and after $_POST variable).

That is what I've seen taking a fast look, maybe there is something more.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing `$pos`. Try this :

```
$pos = strpos($_POST['zodis'], ' ');
```

You have also forgotten the concatenation operator (`.`), in your query.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `zodziai` (`id` ,`zodis` ,`date`)VALUES (NULL , '" . $_POST['zodis'] . "',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
```

Also avoid using mysql_ functions, PHP discourages using mysql_ functions and mysql_ functions will soon be deprecated, rather, use mysqli class or PDO.

Another suggestion, rather than sending `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the query, create the table field using the following constraint

```
`date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and then pass `NULL` in the query, this will automatically set the `date` field in the corresponding row as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.